# converting a string into ordered list in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, methods

```
top_imdb_movies = ['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather', 'The Dark Knight']
```

How would i iterate over top_imdb_movies to display the following ordered list:

```
1.The Shawshank Redemption
2.The Godfather
3.The Dark Knight
```

Comment: A `for` loop, possibly using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate with a start value of 1 as follows:

```
top_imdb_movies = ['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather', 'The Dark Knight']

for i, movie in enumerate(top_imdb_movies, 1):
    print(f'{i}. {movie}')
```

**Output:**

```
1. The Shawshank Redemption
2. The Godfather
3. The Dark Knight
```

Answer (score 0):

```
top_imdb_movies = ['1. The Shawshank Redemption', '2. The Godfather', '3. The Dark Knight']

for i in top_imbd_movies:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer to help readers understand how this works, and solves the problem. You can click the edit button at the bottom of your answer to add an explanation. Additionally, you may find it beneficial reading [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
i=1
for movie in top_imdb_movies:
   print(f"{i}. {movie}"
   i = i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method like so:

```py
top_imdb_movies = ['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather', 'The Dark Knight']

for movie_number, movie in enumerate(top_imdb_movies):
    print(f"{movie_number + 1}. {movie}")
```

output

```py
1. The Shawshank Redemption
2. The Godfather
3. The Dark Knight
```

Comment: Why movie_number=0 ?

Comment: Just to provide a better variable name for the numbers so any one can understand what is happening. Or at least will know how the numbers a generated.

Comment: My point is that you initialise it to zero and it gets re-initialised when the loop starts. It's not necessary to pre-define like that in Python (unlike Java for instance)

Comment: You absolutely right @AlbertWinestein but because I was trying to make the questioner understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

By composing functions:

```
top_imdb_movies = ['The Shawshank Redemption', 'The Godfather', 'The Dark Knight']

print(*map('{}.{}'.format, range(1, 1+len(top_imdb_movies)), top_imdb_movies), sep='\n')
```

Added the `sep='\n'` parameter to `print` and expanding the iterable object with `*` to avoid the `for`-loop

---

If the list is long you can define a template string as a variable to gather better performance, `template = '{}.{}'`

```
template = '{}.{}'
print(*map(template.format, range(1, 1+len(top_imdb_movies)), top_imdb_movies), sep='\n')
```